How to get printed response from async function in Python
I want to get printed response of sync function. for that am using,
StringIO.
import sys
from io import StringIO

def sample():
  print('started to fetch log!')
  print('response:body')
  print('status:200')

def get_log():
  sys.stdout = StringIO()
  sample()
  log = sys.stdout.getvalue()
  sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
  return log

# in sync call,
out = get_log()
print(out)
started to fetch log!
response:body
status:200

but in async call, am unable to get those,
created async wrapper for this sync function.
async def get():
  return asyncio.run(get_log()) 

return None. asyncio never running async function in synchronous. without running synchronous way, am unable to get print response.
Note: I need async wrapper to coupe with existing logics.

Are you ever awaiting get…? Please provide a complete [mre], not a working example and then some vaguely defined non-working case.

If sample and get_log should become async functions, you can await sample in get_log. If only sample should become async, you can call get_log as in synchronous case but replace the call of sample() by asyncio.run(sample()).

ThreadPoolExecutor helped me.
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, long_running_task, task)

@MohideenbinMohammed I'm not finding your original question all that clear, but one thing that stands out is that you are calling out to console functions, which are not asynchronous. Thus, you should indeed use threading to call them when running inside an asyncio event loop. However, there's no need to explicitly create a thread pool executor. You can just use asyncio.to_thread, which creates a default ThreadPoolExecutor if there isn't one already or there's not one passed in.

It is impossible to run regular sync function like that: asyncio.run(sync_func())
For implementing async call, you can use different methods, but because of example, it hard to understand what context of execution is here. Anyway there is one solution that should work. It is possible to execute sync function from async code using loop.run_in_executor for example:
import sys
from io import StringIO

def sample():
    print('started to fetch log!')
    print('response:body')
    print('status:200')

def get_log():
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    sample()
    log = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return log

async def get():
    # get running event loop, in the case it has been already started
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    awaitable_res = loop.run_in_executor(None, get_log)
    res = await awaitable_res
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # if our script is executed as main, but also should work in another situations
    print_res = asyncio.run(get())
    print(print_res)  # print what you expected

